# Add a copy of the question title above answers in the review screen?

Tags: feature-request, review

I am reviewing first-posts and late-answers for a few weeks now and something is annoying me:
Always when there is an answer to be reviewed, I have to scroll down (if the answer is long enough) to see the question. But when I review an answer, it is essentially for me to know, *what the question is about*! I admit I usually don't read the full question therefore, but I always check the *question title* and maybe quickly skim over the questions content to have a rough outline what kind of answers would fit and what not.

So to make this a tiny bit easier and faster, it would be helpful to just add another copy of the question title above the answer. This would also encourage more other people to compare whether the answer fits properly to the posted question or whether it just looks valid.

What do you think about this feature? Pros / Cons? I think it is easy to code and brings only advantages to the reviewers.